# Video works in IE, Chrome, not FF - Says "Download File"

Tags: mediaelement.js

I was having issues with the player in IE9, it worked in FF/Chrome.

I did some research and found the 'shim' option.  I replaced the 'mode: auto' with the conditional for IE9 found in the other post.

Although this fixed my issues with IE9 and the player still works in Chrome, now I get a weird Download File link in FF.

Any ideas?

URL I'm trying to get working: http://gltlive.1parkplace.com/repairs-for-selling-your-home-in-austin/

Comment: You may find the post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450870/flash-in-mediaelement-js-only-shows-download-file helpful.