# Mediaelement.js Flashfallback is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, mediaelement.js

I want my audio to play if the browser does not support the mime type of a file, in Chrome and Firefox my code works but when it comes to IE9 it stops working.

So Here is my audio snippet markup.

```
<audio id="player2" controls="controls">
    source id="mp3_path" src="audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></source>
</audio>
```

Here is initilization code for medialement.

```
  $('audio').mediaelementplayer({
        audioWidth: 960,
        audioHeight: 30,
        preload:true,
         plugins: ['flash'],
        features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume'],
        flashName: 'flashmediaelement.swf',
    });
```

and the result is this.

`Download File`

ANy idea to enable flash fallback for audio in IE9?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you have to define the path

```
$('audio').mediaelementplayer({
    audioWidth: 960,
    audioHeight: 30,
    preload:true,
     plugins: ['flash'],
    features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume'],
    pluginPath: '/myflashpath/',
    flashName: 'flashmediaelement.swf',
});
```

Comment: isn't it the flashmediaelement.swf is the plugin path?

Comment: based on the documentation, the pluginPath is the folder that contains the flash files

Comment: I already tried your suggestion but still did not work. the flash fallback is working for FF but not on IE9

Comment: can you give me an url? i can check here

Comment: sorry, it is not hosted online.

Comment: mmmm check this, is the same question, maybe you can find an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450870/flash-in-mediaelement-js-only-shows-download-file